# Add new columns with defined values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table named `dmat`. I want to add each character of `missing_snps` to  `dmat` as new column and assign all rows as zero. The output remains in the same class as it was.
I would appreciate any suggestion.

```
dmat <- structure(list(`1:27950613:G:A` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27950883:CTA:C` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27952180:A:G` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27953106:A:G` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27953374:G:T` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27953514:T:TA` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27953608:T:C` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27954027:G:A` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27954415:T:C` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `1:27962685:T:C` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

missing_snps <- c("1:169858888:G:A", "1:16985867657:T:A", "1:132862874:G:A")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dmat[,c("1:169858888:G:A", "1:16985867657:T:A", "1:132862874:G:A")] <- 0`

or `dmat[, missing_snps] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`,

```
dmat <- setDT(dmat)
missing_snps <- c("1:169858888:G:A", "1:16985867657:T:A", "1:132862874:G:A")
dmat[,(missing_snps ):=0]
```

**Output**

```
> dmat[,..missing_snps ]
    1:169858888:G:A 1:16985867657:T:A 1:132862874:G:A
 1:               0                 0               0
 2:               0                 0               0
 3:               0                 0               0
 4:               0                 0               0
 5:               0                 0               0
 6:               0                 0               0
 7:               0                 0               0
 8:               0                 0               0
 9:               0                 0               0
10:               0                 0               0
```

The columns you want to mutate has been added.